# How to install firewall under a router

Tags: cisco, firewall

Recently purchased Sophos Xg 125 firewall, previously am using Cisco Rv325 router with 4 Vlan,

My question about for configuration is that
1.how to configure my firewall under this router because previously am using Cisco Rv325 router with 4 vlan. Is it possible to use this vlan under my firewall..if yes how??
2. Where should i create public ip and all

please help.....

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Do you want to migrate your firewall policies from Cisco to Sophos? Or combine both devices? Or would you simply like to know how to start configuring the Sophos? Need help with VLANs? Please ask for specific problems only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More details would be much appreciated but hopefully this still helps.

Youd need to create subinterfaces on your firewall, and tag them for the right vlans. So, the firewall still needs a subinterface tagged with a vlan to match each vlan that is routed on the switch.

There may also need to be a trunk link so that traffic can get from the client to the subinterface on the firewall.

Traffic from the vlans routed on the switch should use vlan 3 to be routed across to the firewall.

Furthermore, if the port in routed mode, and there are no VLAN tag associated with the connection so you will not be able to tag other VLANs on the firewall and expect it to work.